# Linearize objective function in MILP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

I have an objective function that I want to linearize but want to confirm that I'm doing it correctly. There are some constraints that are linear in $x$ but they're unimportant for the problem. The objective is:
$$\max_{x}p^Tx-\rho\|Ax\|_q$$
Subject to:
$$A\in \mathbf{R}^{nxn}$$
$$p\in \mathbf{R}^n$$
$$x\in\{0,1\}^n$$
$$\rho\in\mathbf{R}^+$$

I'm investigating the cases where $q=1$ and $q=\infty$. This is what I've simplified $q=1$ to:
$$\max_{x, z}p^Tx-\rho \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i$$
Subject to:
$$A\in \mathbf{R}^{nxn}$$
$$-z\leq Ax \leq z $$
$$z\in \mathbf{R}^n$$
$$x\in\{0,1\}^n$$
$$\rho\in\mathbf{R}^+$$

This feels straight forward from standard LP but just want to confirm this would hold for MILP as well. I may be missing something where this doesn't extend to MILP.

For the $q=\infty$ case, the objective is:
$$\max_{}\{p^Tx-\rho*\max_{}\{|Ax|\}\}$$

I've simplified this to:
$$\max_{x, z}p^Tx-\rho z$$
Subject to:
$$z\geq (Ax)_i \hspace{0.5cm} \forall i \; in \;1 \;to \;n$$
$$z\geq -(Ax)_i \hspace{0.5cm} \forall i \; in \;1 \;to \;n$$
$$A\in \mathbf{R}^{nxn}$$
$$z\in \mathbf{R}$$
$$x\in\{0,1\}^n$$
$$\rho\in\mathbf{R}^+$$

I'm not sure I can transform the inner maximization like that. I know this works for $\min\{\max\{Ax\}\}$ or $\max\{\min\{Ax\}\}$ but does this follow for $\max\{-\max\{Ax\}\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both linearizations are correct.  Here's a derivation for $\max\{-\max\{\}\}$:
\begin{align}
\max_x\left\{-\max_i f_i(x)\right\}
&= \max_x\left\{\min_i \{-f_i(x)\}\right\} \\
&= \max_x\left\{y: y \le -f_i(x) \text{ for all $i$}\right\} \\
&= \max_x\left\{y: -y \ge f_i(x) \text{ for all $i$}\right\} \\
&= \max_x\left\{-z: z \ge f_i(x) \text{ for all $i$}\right\} &&\text{[take $z=-y$]}
\end{align}